# SQL stored procedure query (insert)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, foreach

I've got my two tables with following design:

products

> |id(int 11)|name(varchar 11)|category(int 11)|price(float)

price_avg

> |category(int 11)|date(timestamp, will be set automatic)|price_avg (float)

Now I would like to create a SQL stored procedure, so when I call the procedure it calculates the average price of each category and saves avg_price and category into table 'price_avg'.

My main problems are the loop which checks each category and to save the calculated amount directly into new table, not returning this to the user.
I know the basic procedure would look in some way like this:

```
    CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE avg_price
                /* no need of using a input parameter
                */
        ()
/* is RETURN correct? I would like to save the return directly
*/
RETURNS ( category INT(11),
          price    FLOAT,
                )
AS
BEGIN
    /* how to loop each category and do the calculation?
    */

  DO SUSPEND;
END
```

All in all I'm not sure how to save the calculated average prices directly into another table and how to loop through each product and calculate category avg_price on the fastest way.

Comment: I recommend you not to do business logic in the database, I think will be much easier and even faster if you do that in your code and then just save the data on the database

Comment: No it's not business logic, just a task in a book I'm reading, I just want to solve it :/. I know doing these dings in for example PHP and saving them after manipulating in database is much easier.